# Find count group by id in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count

I need some help to solve this query. I have a table which contains the ages of the passengers who are going to stay in a room which is mentioned below:

```
Age    RoomId 
-----    ---
 1        1
12        1
 8        1
19        1
3         2
12        2
18        2
21        3
```

Also, I have properties table which contains the maximum age of the child and maximum age of the infant. Based on the age of the passenger, I need to segregate them to adult, child, and infant to each of the properties.

`Properties` table structure

```
Property Id Maximum_child_age  Maximum_infant_age
-------------------------------------------------
1                11                     2
```

Desired output

```
RoomId  Adult Child Infant PropertyId
--------------------------------
 1       2       1      1      1
 2       2       1      0      1
 3       1       0      0      1
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far to achieve this yourself? Please do share your attempts first.

Comment: Also, which version of SQL Server?   SQL 2008, SQL 2017, etc.

Comment: @Sparky : SQL server 2017

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN pas.age > ppt.Maximum_child_age THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Adult,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pas.age BETWEEN Maximum_infant_age AND ppt.Maximum_child_age THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Child,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pas.age < ppt.Maximum_infant_age THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Infant,
    ppt.id
FROM 
    passengers pas
    CROSS JOIN properties ppt
GROUP BY ppt.id
```

Comment: It gives me an error because of "ON" Keyword, is it ok to use on condition in cross join ?

Comment: @Harry : sorry that was a typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Cross join the properties and then do conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT count(CASE
               WHEN pa.ages > pr.maximum_child_age THEN
                 1
             END) adult,
       count(CASE
               WHEN pa.ages > pr.maximum_infant_age
                    AND pa.ages <= pr.maximum_child_age THEN
                 1
             END) child,
       count(CASE
               WHEN pa.ages <= pr.maximum_infant_age THEN
                 1
             END) infant,
       pr.propertyid
       FROM passengers pa
            CROSS JOIN properties pr
       GROUP BY pr.propertyid;
```